# Refer to Form Control Without Specific Naming

Tags: ms-access, reference, vba

I have a form with numerous images, each of which performs a series of actions when clicked. I can create a Private Sub with all of the actions for each button, however I think this is inefficient. Rather, I'd like to record all the actions in one Macro and then call this Macro when each image is clicked. To do so, I'd need the single Macro to refer to the current image selected and not refer to any image by name. Is this possible?

My current code includes the following:

```
Me.Image001.BorderColor = RGB(1, 1, 1)
Me.Image001.BorderWidth = 2
Me.Image001.BorderStyle = 1
```

I'd need to amend this so that it amends the border colour/width/style etc of whichever image is selected, and not a specific named image ('Image001').

Thanks!

Comment: Im pretty sure you would have to read the index of the picture clicked and then pass that to the master macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always create a Standard Sub, then call it on the click of the button. Something like

```
Public Sub changeColor(frm As Form, ctrl As Control)
    frm.Controls(ctrl.Name).BorderColor = RGB(1, 1, 1)
    frm.Controls(ctrl.Name).BorderWidth = 2
    frm.Controls(ctrl.Name).BorderStyle = 1
End Sub
```

So when you click an image all you have to do is,

```
Private Sub Image001_Click()
    changeColor Me, Image001
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. The theory seems right, however I get an 'application-defined or object-defined error'. Could this be that Image001 is not a valid Control? This may be a simple question, but would an image be classified as a Control or something else?

Comment: Okay, I tested this, it is because it needs the name of the control rather than the Control itself. Please try the edited code.

Comment: Can´t you just change the properties of `ctrl` itself? Is there a need to get its name, get the control of the form by that name (which will be the exaxt same as ctrl) and change the props of that?

Comment: @luk2302, Could you please add that as answer so I could upvote? I am sure if you think that it was a better answer, it needs recognition.

Comment: I am not sure about it and do not really have the time to test it - I was only guessing that it would be possible to do it that way.

Comment: @luk2302 Ah I see, well that's nice ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should use event sinking.
With event sinking you could bind to an event your own procedures.
You can see an example here http://p2p.wrox.com/access-vba/37472-event-triggered-when-any-control-changed.html
In simple words you create a module where you bind the event to your specific implementation . Then on the form you are interested you create  a collection where you register the controls you want to "follow" the event sinking...
My sub sinking for checkboxes (i have alot)
1st a class module name SpecialEventHandler

```
Option Compare Database

Private WithEvents chkbx As CheckBox
Private m_Form As Form
Private Const mstrEventProcedure = "[Event Procedure]"

Public Function init(chkbox As CheckBox, frm As Form)
  Set chkbx = chkbox
  Set m_Form = frm
  'Debug.Print frm.Name
  chkbx.AfterUpdate = mstrEventProcedure
End Function

Private Sub chkbx_AfterUpdate()
  'your Code here
End Sub



Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set chkbx = Nothing
    Set m_Form = Nothing
End Sub
```

Then on the form you want to use event sinking

```
Option Compare Database
Dim spEventHandler As SpecialEventHandler
Private colcheckBoxes As New Collection

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
  Dim ctl As Control

  For Each ctl In Me.Detail.Controls
  Select Case ctl.ControlType

    Case acCheckBox
        Set spEventHandler = New SpecialEventHandler
        spEventHandler.init Controls(ctl.NAME), Me
        colcheckBoxes.Add spEventHandler
    End Select
Next ctl
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for promoting WithEvents.